# jquery plugin object configuration with .data()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Its probably stupid noob general javascript question but ive been trying to find an answer for days.

Lets say i use jquery plugin that takes object as settings (i will show on flexbox called fluixbox) and i want it to take some of the settings from html.

html:

```
<a data-color="rgba(40,25,255,1)"> My colorful image </a>
```

javascript:

```
$("a").fluidbox({ overlayColor:   $(this).data("color") })
```

I think its pretty self explenatory, i tried to do everything. I think problem must be something with scope. If i just create function that returns rgba(40,25,255,1) and put it instead  $(this).data("color") then it does work.

Thank you for any response.

Comment: it is scope, the use of `this` within the attribute is not referring to `a`, but defaults to the global `window` object. you need to assign the color to a variable, then use that variable as the value instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use $(this) in that scope, you're not referring to your anchor, you're probably referring to the Window object.

You can use:

```
$("a").each(function() {
    $(this).fluidbox({ overlayColor: $(this).data("color") });
});
```

This should work, since the function inside the "each" method changes the scope to each DOMElement you're iterating.

Comment: Thank you! This works however because of your solution i found out that i tried the same thing before and dumped it. It turns out that that particual plugin Fluidbox changes options to a class that it applies globaly so the option is just rewritten everytime and latest rewrite is basicaly applied to everything.

I will have to change the approach. Anyway this answer pushed me forwad and IS the solution to my question.

Thank you very much.